# Intellij (via gradle) JavaFX Menus dont show and Textfields are not editable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, javafx, java-8

If I open a JavaFX application from IntelliJ two things don't work:

- editing textfields (they get focused but I can't enter text)
- when I click on a Menu the Items don't show up

I'm using Gradle to build my project however if I execute `gradle run` manually everthing works. The Problem only occurs when opening it via IntelliJ.

I'm using Java 8, Gradle 2.12 and IntelliJ 2016.1 (on Linux).

Where do I post this bug (if it is one)?

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.76-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="package.to.Controller">
<top>
    <!-- MENU -->
    <MenuBar>
        <menus>
            <Menu text="Items">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem text="item1" onAction="#bla1"/>
                    <MenuItem text="item2" onAction="#bla2"/>
                    <MenuItem text="item3" onAction="#bla3"/>
                    <MenuItem text="item4" onAction="#bla4"/>
                    <MenuItem text="item5" onAction="#bla5"/>
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>
</top>
...
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Unlikely that it is a IJ problem. Coding and Runnign JavaFX works fine here. Do you really create your stuff properly? E. g. do you create and manipulate your JavaFX components **exclusively** on the JavaFX Platform thread?

Comment: @clotodex Could you post a code snippet of your Main application class? It would help us deduce where eventual problems with your code might be (if any), at the very least it could help us exclude that from the list of possible problems.

Comment: I noticed that it is not always happening (mostly when I change something in the fxml and then run).